# Django smart-select ChainedModelChoiceField not working properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I need to have a dependent dropdown box using smart-select where I filter by Country, State, City and finally Area. These are the relevant models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    country_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
class State(models.Model):
    country=models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)

class City(models.Model):
    state=models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Area(models.Model):
    city=models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And this is what I have tried in Forms:

```
class CountryFormChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.country_name

class HomeForm(forms.Form):
    #some other fields
    country_name=CountryFormChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.filter(is_active=True), label='Select Country')
    state_name=ChainedModelChoiceField('common','State','country_name','country','common','Country','country',show_all=False,auto_choose=False)
    city_name=ChainedModelChoiceField('common','City','state_name','state','common','State','state',show_all=False,auto_choose=False)
    area_name=ChainedModelChoiceField('common','Area','city_name','city','common','City','city',show_all=False,auto_choose=False)
```

But in the site, only the country field has values in the dropdown, and even after selecting a country the other fields are not showing any options. This is the template:

```
{% load has_group %}
{% block content %}
<div class="home">
    {% if request.user|has_group:"Organization" %}
    <h1>Signed in as Organization</h1>
    {% else %}
    <h1>Welcome to Gamefront</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" class="homeform">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.media.js }}
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
    </form>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

What could be the issue?